# Why doesn't the ubuntu installer recognize partitions made by the Windows disk management console?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, operating-systems

I am trying to install a ubuntu OS on my laptop, with an existing Windows 10. I plan to install unbuntu on a 1TB drive partitioned into three volumes: `F`,`U` and `Z`. The volume `U` is the one I plan to install ubuntu on and is newly created, while `F` and `Z` contain existing files (they are all of NTFS format). But when I open the installer of ubuntu, it only shows the whole drive, and the usage of this drive is labeled "unknown". Since I have other files on `F` and `Z`, I am afraid installing would overwrite them.

How can I make the installer recognize the new volume `U`? Can I do it with Windows disk management or some other software?

---

**Update:**
Now I have had my `U` volume deleted, and it looks like this on Windows:
[image]

But in the installer it looks like this:
[image]

where `/dev/sda` is my 1TB hard drive and `/dev/sda3` should be `D`+`F`+`Z`+unallocated space. As you can see, I can't find the unused space in the installer. I tried formatting the unused space into NTFS, exFAT, ext4, etc. before starting the installer. None of these helps.

Comment: Consider using Ubuntu in VM which is much more flexible? You can even use that partition directly in Ubuntu inside VM.

Comment: @jw_ I've used VM before. But I think I'll stick to a real OS, partly because VM doesn't responde as quickly, and partly because of my OCD... Thanks for the advice though. Someone else might find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you delete your newly created partition `U` and let the Ubuntu installer create it's own partitions during the intsallation process.

Ubuntu usally creates itself more than one partition with various file systems and sizes. So for beginners it's best to leave that task up to the installer.

Comment: I know what you mean. But what I am saying is, the ubuntu installer sees `U`,`F`,`Z` as a whole, and does not recognize the used space. Doing what you said might overwrite the files that are originally stored in these places.

Comment: Well you said: "The volume U is the one I plan to install ubuntu on and is newly created" so I see no problem deleting it on windows, and then in the ubuntu installer select a section that is called "unused space" or something as your destination. Do you think that could work?

Comment: Deleting it on Windows is fine. But there is no "unused space" appearing in the installer. I'll upload two screenshot in my answer.